# How do I keep fields from being in the same row?

Tags: views

I've attached a pic to show what I'm talking about.  I'm using 'fluid-grid' in Views.  Drupal 7.  Thanks so much![1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the class of the element/field above (using your browser's developing tool) and try this CSS:

```
.field_my_field:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

Change the "field_my_field" with your class name. Clear Drupal cache.
It should push the next element below.